# How to target dynamically created elements for 'click' eventListener's

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create an etch & sketch with a reset button that will reset all of my created divs which are appeneded to a container. I cannot seem to target the created div's to reset the color back to white. I get a `divCells.setAttribute is not a function`. It will work on the body, container etc...but not the created divs. I console log'ed the div cells and it does show up in the console. How do I target the divCells for an EventListener?

```js
const body = document.querySelector('#body');
let container = document.querySelector('#container');
let buttonContainer = document.querySelector('#buttonContainer');
let reset = document.querySelector('#resetButton');
let x = 0;

let gridCells = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    divCells = document.createElement(`div`);
    divCells.classList.add('divCells');
    divCells.setAttribute('style', `height: 1%; width: 1%; background-color: white;
                                margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;`);
    container.appendChild(divCells);
  }
}

gridCells()

let resetContainer = function() {
  let container = document.querySelector('#container');
  console.log(container);
  let divCells = document.querySelectorAll('.divCells');
  console.log(divCells);
  divCells.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red');
}
container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
})
reset.addEventListener(`click`, function(event) {
  resetContainer();
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
}

#resetButton {
  width: 25%;
  height: 40%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#reset {
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 10%;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button id="resetButton">
            Reset
        </button>
  </div>
  <script src="etch.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please always, always, always include the code you are asking about right here in your question. If your 3rd party link dies over time, your question here is meaningless.

Comment: Please include all information necessary to understand your problem in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This doesn't have anything to do with dynamically created elements.** The problem is in your reset function where you've got:

```
let divCells = document.querySelectorAll('.divCells');
divCells.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red');
```

[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a node list (a container of 0 or more elements). Collections don't have a `setAttribute` property, individual elements do.

You'll need to loop through all the items in the collection and work on each of them separately, like this:

```
divCells.forEach(function(cell){
  cell.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red');
});
```

The reason why it works in your `gridCells` function is because when that function executes, `divCells` is being assigned to the single element returned from `document.createElement()`, not the collection returned from `.querySelectorAll()`.

**Additional Notes:**

- You don't really need to use `setAttribute` in this case, you can
  just access the `style` property on your element references directly,
  like this:

  cell.style = "...";
- Instead of using the `style` attribute in the first place, just
  create a CSS class and apply it to the elements with
  `element.classList.add("classNname")`. This will clean up your
  JavaScript quite a bit and is easier to work with than inline styles.
- Your `reset` element has an event listener attached to it that simply
  calls the `resetContainer` function. Just set your callback to that
  function in the first place instead of having the callback call that
  one.